# Как сделать копию записи с отношениями в бд?

Tags: laravel

У меня есть таблицы Orders, и связывающая таблица Equipment_order.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне сделать копию записи в Orders со всеми отношениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я перепробовал несколько способов (atach, sync), и не один не дал нужного результат. Чаще всего в связывающей таб. появляется запись но с пустыми полями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод [replicate](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#replicating-models) для создания несохраненной копии модели. После создания этой копии вам нужно подгрузить нужные отношения, сохранить копию используя push метод Eloquent модели и отношения через sync.

Ниже копия [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895126/clone-an-eloquent-object-including-all-relationships) из англоязычного SO:

```
//копируем свойства
$new = $this->replicate();

//Сохраняем копию чтобы был её идентификатор
$new->push();

// сбросить отношения чтобы можно было выбрать какие сохранять из копируемой модели
$this->relations = [];

// загрузить нужные отношения для сохранения из копируемой модели
$this->load('relation1','relation2');

// сохраняем выбранные отношения из копируемой в новую копию
foreach ($this->relations as $relationName => $values){
    $new->{$relationName}()->sync($values);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое'

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот таким образом

```
$order = Order::with('equipments')->find(1);

$clone = $order->toArray();
$equipments = $clone['equipments'];
unset($clone['equipments'], $clone['id']);

$clone_order_id = Order::insertGetId($clone);

if (!empty($equipments) && count($equipments) > 0) {
    foreach ($equipments as $equipment) {
        $equipment['order_id'] = $clone_order_id;
        EquipmentOrder::insert($equipment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!